IBM Datacap PIX QRCode
I am working on a project that requires to Read a QRCode. This QrCode is for Instantly payments Named PIX in Brazil.
Does anyone knows how to set this reading properlly
once the PIX QrCode can collect all the info from the doc?
eg. Name, due date , amount, and institute to be paied.
I've tried the standard QRCode reading, but it only brings the raw code from the QRCode not all the informations

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs much improvement.
